# ACE Syntax highlighter for live code editor not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, ace-editor, codemirror

So i am trying to build a code editor which shows output of html in iframe. but there is some trouble. i used codemirror before now i am using ACE but something goes wrong here as it keeps showing me "xxxxxx" and numbers. what is the correct way to use it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/ace.js"></script>
   <style>
      #jsEditor{height:300px;}
   </style>
  </head>

  <body>  
     <div id="jsEditor"></div>
     <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
     <button onclick="refresh()">Click</button>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         var e=ace.edit("jsEditor");
         e.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/html");
         e.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
         e.getSession().setTabSize(2);
         e.renderer.setShowGutter(false);

         function refresh(){
            var textval=document.getElementById('jsEditor').textContent;
            document.getElementById('frame').srcdoc=textval;
          }     
     </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[This is the output i get ][2]

https://jsfiddle.net/fc0cjo9z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ace renders to dom only the visible portion of the text, and adds some nodes that do not correspond to any text.
So instead of `document.getElementById('jsEditor').textContent` you need to call the `getValue()` method of the editor. in your example change the line with textContent to

```
var textval=e.getValue();
```